# Return $\mu$ and volatility $\sigma$ for tangency portfolio of DOW30 too large?

Tags: markowitz

I am calculating GMV and TAN mu and sigma as well as weights using the straightforward derivations, such as:

\begin{equation}
\mu_{gmv}=\frac{\mathbf{1}'\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu}}{\boldsymbol{\mu}'\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu}},
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sigma_{gmv}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\boldsymbol{\mu}'\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu}}},
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{w}_{gmv}=\frac{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{1}}{\mathbf{1}'\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{1}},
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\mu_{tan}=\frac{\boldsymbol{\mu}'\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu}}{\mathbf{1}'\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu}},
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sigma_{tan}=\frac{\sqrt{\boldsymbol{\mu}'\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu}}}{|\mathbf{1}'\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu}|},
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{w}_{tan}=\frac{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu}}{\mathbf{1}'\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu}}.
\end{equation}

If we let 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
        a &= \mathbf{1}'\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{1}\\              % ones(j) * UTU(j, k) * ones(k)
        b &= \mathbf{1}'\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu}\\        % ones(j) * UTU(j, k) * fbar(k)
        c &= \boldsymbol{\mu}'\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu}\\  % fbar(j) * UTU(j, k) * fbar(k)
        d &= ac - b ^ 2,\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

then the $\sigma_{eff}$ for each mean, $\mu_{eff}$, in the orthogonal portfolios on the efficient frontier line is 
\begin{equation}
\sigma_{eff} =\sqrt{\frac{a \mu_{eff}^2 - 2 b \mu_{eff} + c}{d}}.
\end{equation}

However, when I plot the efficient frontier of the daily log-returns for the DOW30 for the last two years (plotted log-scale on returns just to show the GMV mean), I noticed the mean and sigma for the tangency portfolio are much greater than the mean and sigma for the stocks themselves.   The tangency weights are also quite large as well.

By the way, the sum of the stock-specific weights for the GMV and tangency portfolios are both one, respectively.

Should I not use log-returns, but rather use the straightforward price returns to generate the covariance matrix $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ and the stock-specific mean return $\mu$?

[image: mean and sigma]
[image: weights]

Comment: To me "tangency portfolio" requires knowing the interest rate $r_f$. But in your calculations above I don't see $r_f$ anywhere. What do _you_ mean by tangency portfolio? Or are you using 0 for the interest rate?

Comment: Yes, using zero for the interest rate, but the mean and sigma for the tan portfolio seem almost an order of magnitude too large.  There's something going on with weights in spite of summing to unity?

Comment: OK, formulas look alright. What kind of data did you use to estimate your covariance matrix? 24 monthly returns? And you have how many securities 30?

Comment: Another thing to check, as you said, is the size of the weights. Is there one weight that is a big positive number and another that is a big negative?

Comment: The covariance matrix was based on daily log-returns for the 30 DOW stocks from the last two years, so the number of days is in the high 400s.  I also compared results of calculations with other online return and covariance data for calculating GMV and TAN weights, and the resulting weights, means, and sigmas were the same as those published.  Maybe the CAPM line truly intersects the efficient frontier line way out at high mean and sigma values?   Maybe I'll cut the #stocks down to 5-10 and see what happens.

Comment: OK, it seems you have enough observations to estimate a decent covariance  matrix, i.e. $T \gg N$. So that is not the problem. Next culprit might be the expected returns. Do check what the max and min weights are, that might give a clue.

Comment: The TAN weights are in the far right column of the spreadsheet in the OP.  One is high (>3.5) and a few are <-2.

Comment: There are two problems here.  Log returns overstate returns by two percent and understate risk by plus or minus four percent over raw data.  The second problem is a distributional problem.  A paper presented at the Southwestern Finance Association conference this year derived the distribution of returns for stocks and they violate the assumptions of your equations.  You can find it in their proceedings as "The Distribution of Returns."

Comment: Looked at the paper and there were no empirical data used, no simulations performed, and no worked examples for modifying portfolio optimization analytic solutions presented in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which I discovered via comparison of using log-returns vs. returns.  I also trimmed down the number of stocks.  When using log-returns vs returns we get the following efficient frontiers.  The log-returns results in the most textbook looking plot, but note that the TAN point is way out to the right -- and that the slope of the CAPM line is low.  Whereas, the returns results in the TAN point intersecting the CAPM line near the GMV point, and the CAPM line has a very steep slope.  Overall, I think using log-returns is the way to go.

[image]
[image]